# Destructuring Object with Enum in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I try to find a way to destructuring keys of the object in ES6 with keys of another object (Eum) and create variables. for example my enum is

```
const KEYS = {
  name:'name',
  family:'age'
}
```

and my object is :

```
const myObject = {
  name:'John',
  family:'Doe'
}
```

and what I want is destructuring `myObject` with keys of `KEYS` I know the below code is wrong but something like this :

```
 const {KEYS.name} = myObject
```

so it creates a variable with name `name` that is the value of `KYES.name` but as I say it raised a syntax error . does anyone has an idea for a destructuring object with an enum.

Comment: You're essentially looking for a dynamic variable name. While it's possible with `eval`, it's a very bad idea - figure out a better way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: You can't do that (other than with `eval` or its cousin `new Function`). But more to the point, why would you want to? What possible use would it be to have a dynamic variable name? What's your underlying goal here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and an [object property assignment pattern [YDKJS: ES6 & Beyond]](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#object-property-assignment-pattern) for it.

[`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) is a reserved property of `window` and may lead to unexpected results by changing it.

```js
const
    KEYS = { name: 'name', family: 'age' },
    myObject = { name:'John', family:'Doe' };

({ [KEYS.name]: window[KEYS.name] } = myObject);
 
console.log(name);
```

Comment: Which isn't what the OP said he's trying to do.

Comment: Dynamic variable names are indeed a bad idea (as I said in the comments), but again, this is answering a question that the OP didn't ask.